# Liquibase in Spring boot application keeps 10 connections open

Tags: spring, spring-boot, liquibase

I'm working on a Spring Boot application with Liquibase integration to setup the database. We use a different user for the database changes which we configured using the application.properties file

```
liquibase.user=abc
liquibase.password=xyz
liquibase.url=jdbc:postgresql://something.eu-west-1.rds.amazonaws.com:5432/app?ApplicationName=${appName}-liquibase
liquibase.enabled=true
liquibase.contexts=dev,postgres
```

We have at this moment 3 different microservices in deployment and we noticed that for every running instance, Liquibase opens 10 connections and it never closes these connections unless we stop the application. This basically means that in development we regularly hit the connection limit of our Amazon RDS instance.

Right now, in development, 40 of 74 active connections are occupied by Liquibase. If we ever want to go to production with this, having autoscaling enabled for all the microservices, that would mean we'll have to over-scale the database in order not to hit any connection limits.

Is there a way to

- tell liquibase to not use a connection pool of 10 connections
- tell liquibase to stop or close the connections

So far I found no documentation on how to do this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks to the response of Slava I managed to fix the problem with following datasource configuration class

```
@Configuration
public class LiquibaseDataSourceConfiguration {

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LiquibaseDataSourceConfiguration.class);

    @Autowired
    private LiquibaseDataSourceProperties liquibaseDataSourceProperties;

    @LiquibaseDataSource
    @Bean
    public DataSource liquibaseDataSource() {
        DataSource ds =  DataSourceBuilder.create()
                .username(liquibaseDataSourceProperties.getUser())
                .password(liquibaseDataSourceProperties.getPassword())
                .url(liquibaseDataSourceProperties.getUrl())
                .driverClassName(liquibaseDataSourceProperties.getDriver())
                .build();
        if (ds instanceof org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource) {
            ((org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource) ds).setInitialSize(1);
            ((org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource) ds).setMaxActive(2);
            ((org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource) ds).setMaxAge(1000);
            ((org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource) ds).setMinIdle(0);
            ((org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource) ds).setMinEvictableIdleTimeMillis(60000);
        } else {
            // warnings or exceptions, whatever you prefer
        }

        LOG.info("Initialized a datasource for {}", liquibaseDataSourceProperties.getUrl());
        return ds;
    }

}
```

The documentation of the properties can be found on the site of Tomcat: https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jdbc-pool.html

- initialSize: The initial number of connections that are created when the pool is started
- maxActive: The maximum number of active connections that can be allocated from this pool at the same time
- minIdle: The minimum number of established connections that should be kept in the pool at all times
- maxAge:  Time in milliseconds to keep this connection. When a connection is returned to the pool, the pool will check to see if the now - time-when-connected > maxAge has been reached, and if so, it closes the connection rather than returning it to the pool. The default value is 0, which implies that connections will be left open and no age check will be done upon returning the connection to the pool.
- minEvictableIdleTimeMillis: The minimum amount of time an object may sit idle in the pool before it is eligible for eviction.

So it does not appear to be a connection leak, it's just the default configuration of the datasource which is not optimal for Liquibase *if you use a dedicated datasource*. I don't expect this to be a problem if the liquibase datasource is your primary datasource.

Comment: I think the solution by wmilewski is probably a better solution since it resolves the issue at the root rather than a workaround.

Answer (score 6):

Update: This has been fixed in [2.5.0-M2](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/releases/tag/v2.5.0-M2) and Liquibase now uses a `SimpleDriverDataSource` without a connection pool.

Original answer: This change to connection pool management was introduced in Spring Boot version `2.0.6.RELEASE`, and only takes effect if you use Spring Boot Actuator. There is an actuator endpoint (enabled by default) which allows you to get change sets applied by Liquibase. For this to work Liquibase keeps its database connections open. You can disable the endpoint with `management.endpoint.liquibase.enabled = false`, in which case the connection pool used by Liquibase will be shutdown after the initial run.

- GitHub issue related to this change: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/13832
- Spring Boot Actuator (see `12. Liquibase`: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.6.RELEASE/actuator-api/html/

Comment: good answer: I wonder why the problem after a long time has not yet been solved by Liquibase : it is not yet possible, by modifying the spring configuration file, to change the number of connections allocated. But then why is the default 10? Wasn't one enough?

Comment: @obe6 I raised this with Spring Boot owners - the default implementation will change for Liquibase to use a `SimpleDriverDataSource` which does not have a connection pool, just a (new) single connection on every call. It can still be customised with @LiquibaseDataSource https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/24944

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why liquibase doesn't close a connection, maybe it's a bug and you should [create an issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/new) for that.

To set connection pool for liquibase you have to create a custom data source and mark it with `@LiquibaseDataSource` annotation.

Related issues provide more details:

- [Possibility to specify custom dataSource configuration for liquibase only](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/6604)
- [Add LiquibaseDataSource annotation](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/pull/6614)

Comment: Ok, that can be very interesting because with a custom datasource I can specify the `datasource.dbcp2.initial-size=1`

Comment: Using the following code I managed to reduce the number of connections to 1. However, despite configuring the max-age to 10 seconds, the connection is never closed, which does make me suspect that there is connection leak.
    
     `DataSource ds = DataSourceBuilder.create().username("").password("").url("").driverClassName("").build();`
`((org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource) ds).setInitialSize(1);`
`((org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource) ds).setMaxActive(2);`
`((org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource) ds).setMaxAge(10000);`

Comment: @stephane-nicoll Hi, could you confirm whether keeping opened connections by Liquibase is a bug?