# Liquibase pool setting spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, liquibase

I surprisingly discovered that liquibase creates his own connection pool with default values and therefore holds 10 connections to db. It doesn't use connection pool configured from application.properties. So, I have a couple of questions:

1. What is necessity of own pool?
2. How can I configure this pool?

Comment: Possible duplication of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41636250/liquibase-in-spring-boot-application-keeps-10-connections-open

Comment: @MarcosBarbero hmmm, it seems so, I hope next time I will search better. Do you know if I should delete question or smth else (mark it like duplicate if it is possible, don't know)

Comment: But still there is no answer, how to configure it. If i don't want to disable this actuator feature, but want to have not default 10, but 2 connections. Configuration still isn't that clear.

Answer (score 1):

The linked question has indeed a correct answer. But obviously, 10 connections are taken from the default settings of Hikari Pool (it is the default db connection pool starting from Spring Boot 2.0).

So, here is the modified version of the same configuration but with Hikari instead of tomcat-jdbc:

```
    @LiquibaseDataSource
    @Bean
    public DataSource liquibaseDataSource() {
        DataSource ds = DataSourceBuilder.create()
                .username(liquibaseDataSourceProperties.getUser())
                .password(liquibaseDataSourceProperties.getPassword())
                .url(liquibaseDataSourceProperties.getUrl())
                .driverClassName(liquibaseDataSourceProperties.getDriver())
                .build();
        if (ds instanceof HikariDataSource) {
            ((HikariDataSource) ds).setMaximumPoolSize(2); //10 by default
        }
        return ds;
    }
```